# How are memory addresses placed in an binary files?

Tags: c, assembly, memory, embedded, microcontroller

Im having trouble understanding how the sections in an elf file are loaded into memory and how the addresses are chosen? Embedded systems usually assign specific addresses to the code but where is that put?

Basically, how and when are addresses put in the sections and how is that loaded in both an OS and with ROM or RAM in an embedded system.

Comment: In a multi process environment, each process has it's own virtual memory. The linker usually determines in what address the program image is supposed to be loaded, and it's ok if other programs are in the same address because they simply can't see each other's memory (virtual memory address is not the same address the information actually is in the physical memory). In addition to that, most addressing is done with relative addresses (specifying a memory offset relative to where the instruction is) instead of absolute memory addresses, so code tends to work even if you shuffle it around.

Comment: Are the addresses embedded in the binary files?

Comment: Of course. But as I said, usually they are relative addresses instead of absolute addresses, so it can be a bit difficult to decode.

Comment: In a embedded system a locator is used to specify addresses for the final image being built. Why is that needed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Some embedded boards have flashable ROM and RAM. Programs are flashed onto the ROM and then startup code is ran on powerup to move the code to RAM. The binary image built usually needs to specify exact addresses for the section usually with a linker script. I just need a little clarification on why and how it works.

Comment: Well that concept is unfamiliar to me, the microcontrollers I worked with don't even have enough RAM to load the program into it, the program runs directly from the ROM and the RAM is only used for variables and stack. The RAM, ROM, and whatever other memories are available, are simply addressed sequentially.

Comment: ELF format is *not* used as a direct load in any system, embedded or otherwise, that I know of (unless someone's gone and put a special boot loader on a ROM chip somewhere that understands the linux kernel loading) 

meanwhile have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521277/why-doesnt-bios-load-the-linux-kernel-directly-why-the-mbr-and-all-that-troub

Comment: The memory chips (ROM and RAM) are hard-wired to certain addresses on the board by the wiring itself (I just guess each chip thinks about itself as being addressed from zero, and the upper bits of physical address are used by "memory controller" which will reroute the data request to correct chip - but I actually never studied the HW part of it, if it's multiplexing it like this, or how multiple memory chips are handled, actually interesting question, as the address and data bus is only one, but there are several chips connected to it and only one is used per request ... so I'm just guessing)

Comment: @AhmedMasud you need to look at linux, you need to look at tools like openocd, and countless other places where elf is directly supported.  You may be confused in that an elf file can be used by openocd which is the loader that places the bits/bytes in rom.  yes on an mcu it doesnt make sense for the mcu's bootloader to parse elf.  But that doesnt mean that elf is not used for mcus, it is in cases where the toolchain defaults to elf and the tools are host based (and the vendor of that tool chooses to support elf).

Comment: @Ped7g yes there are varous mechanisms, take a memory stick in your computer each chip is some amount of memory say 4 or 8 or 16 bits wide there is a bus to each or a shared bus and a chip select to each so that each knows when it is its turn.   So each chip thinks of itself as a zero to N-1 address space, but closer to the processor there are additional address bits that decide things like which chip, etc.  Sometimes for dram to improve performance there are addressing games that go on.

Comment: but form the edge of the processor to any peripheral, memory, etc there are one or more busses with decoders and even a uart thinks of itself as having a handful or registers starting with address zero.   it is some logic up stream that has a chip/bus/address/data enable that tells the uart, this transaction and address is for you, the uart then pulls the lower few bits off the address bus and responds to that (to save on chip realestate not uncommon that the other address bits are not actually wired to the peripheral or memory, etc).

Comment: take a flash inside a phone or a flash part or a ram, those might actually be made up of smaller individual ones and the outer layer may look like 32 or 64 bits wide some number of address bits deep, but for performance or other reasons may be made up of narrower or less deep memories (if on average a flash only has to deal with every other access then it has twice the time so you can overall make the performance look faster with the same technology)

Comment: linux kernel loading has historically been somewhat trivial, u-boot and redboot, etc are grossly overcomplicated, the kernel is a self-decompressing baremetal progrma, you simply copy it to ram and jump to it.  there are tags/tables you use for things you want to be runtime generic, say a uart address that you dont want to hardcode into the kernel, you can make a generic 16550 driver and pass the address to the uart at boot time.  but thats all part of the port to a platform, the loading of the kernel is trivial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A specific operating system has a specific set of rules or possibly multiple sets of rules for where a compatible program can be loaded.  The toolchain including default linker script (think gcc hello.c -o hello) made for that platform conforms to these rules.

So for example I decide to create an operating system, for a platform that has an MMU.  Because it has an MMU I can create the operating system such that every program sees the same (virtual) address space.  So I can decide that for applications on my operating system, the memory space starts at 0x00000000 but the entry point must be 0x00001000.  The binary file format supported is a Motorola s-record let's say.

So take a simple program with a simple linker script

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

The disassembly of my simple program

```
00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    1004:   eb000001    bl  1010 <main>
    1008:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    100c:   ef000000    svc 0x00000000

00001010 <main>:
    1010:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    1014:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

And the "binary" file happens to be human readable:

```
S00F00006E6F746D61696E2E737265631F
S3150000100002D9A0E3010000EB0000A0E3000000EF1E
S30D000010100000A0E31EFF2FE122
S70500001000EA
```

and you may or may not notice that the address is indeed in the binary describing where things go.

Being an operating system based program that is loaded into ram we don't have to play too many games with memory, we can assume one flat all ram (read/write) so if there were .data, .bss, etc it can all be packed in there.

For a real operating system it is desirable to have the binary include additional information perhaps the size of the program.  So you can google around the various common file formats and see how this is done, either a simple up front I need this much, or one to many sections individually defined.  And yes, again the "binary" is more than just opcodes and data, I assume you understand that.

The toolchain I used outputs elf formatted files by default but objcopy can be used to create a number of different formats one of which is a raw memory image (which does not contain any address/location information) many/most of the rest contain the machine code and data as well as labels for the debugger/disassembler or addresses for where chunks of this data wants to live in the memory space, etc.

Now when you say embedded and use the words ROM and RAM I assume you mean bare-metal like a microcontroller for example, but even if you mean booting an x86 or full sized ARM or whatever the same things apply.  In the case of an MCU the chip designers have perhaps per the rules of the processor or their own choice have determined the rules for the memory space.  Just like an operating system will dictate the rules.  We are cheating a bit, as a lot of the tools we use today (gnu based) are not really designed for bare-metal but because a generic compiler is a generic compiler and more important a toolchain lends itself for this kind of portability, we can use such tools.  Ideally using a cross compiler meaning the output machine code is not necessarily meant to run on the computer generating that output machine code.  The major difference that matters is that we want to control the linking and libraries, don't link in host operating system based libraries and let us control or for this toolchain have a default linker script that targets our MCU.  So lets say I have an ARM7TDMI based MCU, and the chip designers say I need the binary such that the ROM starts at address 0x00000000 and is of some size, and RAM starts at 0x40000000 and is of some size.  Being an ARM7 the processor starts execution by fetching the instruction at address 0x00000000 and the chip designers have mapped that 0x00000000 to the ROM.

So now my simple program

```
unsigned int xyz;
int notmain ( void )
{
    xyz=5;
    return(0);
}
```

linked like this

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
}
```

gives a disassembly of this

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e3a0d101    mov sp, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
   4:   e38dda01    orr sp, sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
   8:   eb000000    bl  10 <notmain>
   c:   eafffffe    b   c <_start+0xc>

00000010 <notmain>:
  10:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
  14:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 24 <notmain+0x14>
  18:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  1c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  24:   40000000    andmi   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

40000000 <xyz>:
40000000:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

And that would be a perfectly valid program, doesn't do much interesting, but still a perfectly valid program.

First and foremost if you leave out _start, the toolchain gives a warning but still functions just fine. (hmm, actually didn't warn that time, interesting).

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld vectors.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --srec-forceS3 notmain.elf -O srec notmain.srec
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin
```

And now you have the loading issue.  Each MCU is different as to how you load it what tools are available and/or you make your own tools.  Ihex and srec were popular for prom programmers where you had say a separate rom next to your processor and/or the through hole mcu would get plugged into the prom programmer.  raw binary images work too but can quickly get large as will show in a second.  As written above there is .bss but no .data so

```
ls -al notmain.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 40 Oct 21 22:05 notmain.bin
```

40 bytes.  But if I do this for demonstration purposes, even though it wont work correctly:

```
unsigned int xyz=5;
int notmain ( void )
{
    return(0);
}
```

with

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ted
}
```

gives

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <notmain-0x10>:
   0:   e3a0d101    mov sp, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
   4:   e38dda01    orr sp, sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
   8:   eb000000    bl  10 <notmain>
   c:   eafffffe    b   c <notmain-0x4>

00000010 <notmain>:
  10:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

40000000 <xyz>:
40000000:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5
```

and

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user 1073741828 Oct 21 22:08 notmain.bin
```

OUCH!  0x40000004 bytes, which was expected, I asked for a memory image I defined stuff at one address (machine code) and a few bytes at another (0x40000000) so the raw memory image has to be that whole range.

```
hexdump notmain.bin 
0000000 d101 e3a0 da01 e38d 0000 eb00 fffe eaff
0000010 0000 e3a0 ff1e e12f 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000020 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
40000000 0005 0000                              
40000004
```

Instead one would just use the elf file the toolchain generates or maybe an ihex or srecord.

```
S00F00006E6F746D61696E2E737265631F
S3150000000001D1A0E301DA8DE3000000EBFEFFFFEA79
S30D000000100000A0E31EFF2FE132
S3094000000005000000B1
S70500000000FA
```

all the info I need but not a huge file for so few bytes.

Not a hard and fast rule but moving data around is easier today (than a floppy from one computer to another with the prom programmer on it).  And particularly i if you have a bundled IDE that vendor likely uses the toolchains default format, but even if not elf and other similar formats are supported and you don't have to go the route of a raw binary or an ihex or srec.  But it still depends on the tool that takes the "binary" and programs it into the ROM(/FLASH) on the MCU.

Now I cheated to demonstrate the large file problem above, instead you have to do more work when it is not a ram only system.  If you feel the need to have .data or desire to have .bss zeroed then you need to write or use a more complicated linker script that helps you out with the locations and boundaries.  And that linker script is married to the bootstrap that uses linker generated information to perform those tasks.  Basically a copy of .data needs to be preserved in non-volatile memory (ROM/FLASH) but it cant live there at runtime .data is read/write so ideally/typically you use the linker scripts language/magic to state that the .data read/write space is blah, and the flash space is boo at this address and this size so the bootstrap can copy from flash at that address for that amount of data to ram.  And for .bss the linker script generates variables that we save into flash that tell the bootstrap to zero ram from this address to this address.

So operating system defines the memory space, the linker script matches that if you want the program to work.  The system designers or chip designers determine the address space for something embedded and the linker script matches that.  The bootstrap is married to the linker script for that build and target.

---

### Edit

toolchain basics...

```
mov sp,#0x40000000
orr sp,sp,#0x1000
bl notmain
b .


unsigned int xyz;
int notmain ( void )
{
    xyz=5;
    return(0);
}

MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x2000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ted
}
```

My bootstrap, main program and linker script

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -save-temps -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld vectors.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --srec-forceS3 notmain.elf -O srec notmain.srec
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin
```

Some folks will argue and is sometimes true that compiles don't generate assembly any more.  Still the sane way to do it and you will find it more often than not, as in this case...

The bootstrap makes an object which we can disassemble.

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a0d101    mov sp, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
   4:   e38dda01    orr sp, sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
   8:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <notmain>
   c:   eafffffe    b   c <.text+0xc>
```

It's not "linked" so the address this disassembler uses is zero based, and you can see the call to notmain is incomplete, not yet linked.

the compiler generated assembly for the C code

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .fpu softvfp
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "notmain.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global notmain
    .type   notmain, %function
notmain:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    mov r2, #5
    ldr r3, .L2
    mov r0, #0
    str r2, [r3]
    bx  lr
.L3:
    .align  2
.L2:
    .word   xyz
    .size   notmain, .-notmain
    .comm   xyz,4,4
    .ident  "GCC: (15:4.9.3+svn231177-1) 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)"
```

that gets assembled into an object which we can also disassemble.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   4:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 14 <notmain+0x14>
   8:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Now not shown but that object also contains information for the global variable xyz and its size.

The linkers job is perhaps part of your confusion.  It links the objects together such that the result will be sane or will work on the final destination (bare-metal or operating system).

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <notmain-0x10>:
    1000:   e3a0d101    mov sp, #1073741824 ; 0x40000000
    1004:   e38dda01    orr sp, sp, #4096   ; 0x1000
    1008:   eb000000    bl  1010 <notmain>
    100c:   eafffffe    b   100c <notmain-0x4>

00001010 <notmain>:
    1010:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
    1014:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 1024 <notmain+0x14>
    1018:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    101c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    1020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    1024:   00002000    andeq   r2, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

00002000 <xyz>:
    2000:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

I made this linker script so that you can see both .data and .bss moving around.  The linker has filled in all of the .text into the 0x1000 address space and has patched in the call to notmain() as well as how to reach xyz.  It has also allocated/defined the space for the xyz variable in the 0x2000 address space.

And then to your next question or confusion.  It is very much up to the tools that load the system, be it the operating system loading a program into memory to be run, or programming the flash of an MCU or programming the ram of some other embedded system (like a mouse for example which you might not know some of them the firmware is downloaded from the operating system and not all of it burned into a flash /lib/firmware or other locations).

Comment: I appreciate you. Thank you for taking the time to answer that so thoroughly. The linker definitely was the part that was the most confusing. One more question. I get the OS specifies loading rules but on an embedded system would the manufacture of a chip say "code will be run from 0x00004000 in ROM"? So, I would basically need a linker script to put the .text there? Would they specify a location for .data?

Comment: yes exactly.  the processor has its rules for booting and addresses within the processor core, but the memory bus the chip vendor adds be it their own processor or a purchased one like arm, they can map that elsewhere.  for example the stm32 family the application flash is at 0x08000000 for a normal boot that is mirrored into 0x00000000 where the arm processor expects the vector table, you can setup the linker script to be either 0x00000000 based or ideally 0x08000000 based because the window that is mirrored is not necessarily the whole of the user flash.

Comment: but yes you are absolutely right the microcontroller chip vendor ultimately decides or implements a memory map from rom to ram to all of the peripherals and they document that somewhere, so if your code needs that information (a compiled C program needs to get at variables in ram) then you need to link the program using a map that matches that hardware.

Comment: arm does not make chips they make IP.  so for example one cortex-m chip vendor can make a different memory map than another cortex-m chip vendor even with the same version of the same core.  In the case of the arm cortex-m the processor has some rules for address space but that is only within that bus, the chip vendor can choose to make outer busses anything they want.  but usually you will see across the cortex-m chips across vendors a bunch of similarities, but then sometimes differences so dont assume the core completely dominates.